# How to hide or show bootstrap 4 collapse using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to hide/show the bootstrap 4 collapse using checkbox with Jquery

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.card-header').click(function() {
 $(this).find('input[name="question"]').prop('checked', true);
});
</script>`

`<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <div class="checkbox-wrap">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="question" disabled>
             </div>
             <h2 id="question-1">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                     lorem Ipsome
                 </button>
             </h2>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#faq">
             <div class="card-body">
                 <p>lorem posem</p>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>`
```

I have used this code. This will show the checkbox checked while it displays show but won't uncheck when it is collapsed

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Show your html code as well.

Comment: ok will update the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the button attribute i.e `aria-expanded` is `true` or `false` depending on this `checked` or `unchecked` checkboxes.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.card-header').click(function() {
//get the attr aria expanded if true means collapse is shown
  if ($(this).find('button.btn-link').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
    $(this).find('input[name="question"]').prop('checked', false);//unchecked
  } else {
    $(this).find('input[name="question"]').prop('checked', true);
//checked
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <div class="checkbox-wrap">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="question" disabled>
    </div>
    <h2 id="question-1">
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                     lorem Ipsome
                 </button>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#faq">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>lorem posem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <div class="checkbox-wrap">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="question" disabled>
    </div>
    <h2 id="question-2">
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                     lorem Ipsome
                 </button>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>lorem posem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But still, there is a small bug try to collapse the second div both showing checked

Comment: HI, i am not seeing any such behaviour in above demo code .. can you create jsfiddle with original code ? issue might be there

Comment: it's ok I have resolved that issue try using radio button

Answer (score 0):

You are having "disabled" input field, which is not allowing checking of radio, need to enable it first.

```
$('.card-header').click(function() {
  $(this).find('input[name="question"]').prop('disabled', false);
  $(this).find('input[name="question"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/f7coy59u/4/)

Hope You get what u want.

Comment: I'm sorry I have used checkbox this answer is not working for me

Comment: Neeraj, can u explain the question properly? so, I can try to solve

Comment: yea sure I have used  a checkbox for hiding and showing the bootstrap 4 collapse 
for that, I have used a query when the collapse is shown the checkbox will be checked and when it is hidden the checkbox will be unchecked